# How to enable usage of Flight Recorder in Surefire plugin

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin

I have added below properties in pom.xml for surefire plugin but its still filing with below error

```
<argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=512m</argLine>
<argLine>-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures</argLine>
<argLine>-XX:+FlightRecorder</argLine>
```

Error: To use Flight Record first Unlock UnlockCommercialFeatures.

Any suggesting with sample pom.xml configurtion
My observation is when I run Maven build this feature is enabled for main thread but not enabled for the fork thread created by surefire pluin

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `argLine` repeatedly. You need to use something along the lines of

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>@{argLine} -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:StartFlightRecording=duration=1000s,filename=surefire.jfr</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

instead. A similar setup works for failsafe.